# Loop inside loop in redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I have a simple state:

```
const INITIAL_PEOPLE = {
    name: 'Friends',
    list: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Alexander',
            child: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Romuald'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Vanessa'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Alex',
            child: [
                {
                    id: 5,
                    name: 'Jessica'
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to print that. Look at my code

```
 {prople.list.map(person =>
     <li key={person.id}>{person.name}
         {person.child.map(child =>
             {child.name}
          )}
     </li>
 )}
```

First loop works correctly but if I added second loop (child), console catch an error that person.child is undefined. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Is the `child` property defined as an empty array when there is no child?

Answer (score 0):

You were not returning any value from your map function.

```
    {INITIAL_PEOPLE.list.map((person) => {
              return (
                <li key={person.id}>
                  {person.name}
                  {person.child.map((child) => {
                    return child.name;
                  })}
                </li>
              );
            })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be written like this with a check if person have a child array.

```
 {prople.list.map(person =>
     <li key={person.id}>{person.name}
         {person.child && person.child.length && person.child.map(child =>
             {return child.name }
          )}
     </li>
 )}
```

Here before calling the map function for child, we are checking if person has an attribute named `child` and if child is an array by checking if child has a property length by `person.child.length`. Notice the return part in the nested map.

Comment: It works. Could you tell me why we must returning child.name but we don;t returning person.name. In both cases we print data from .map.

Comment: You dont have to use return keyword explucitely. But in that case you have to remove the curlybraces around child.name . This behavior is called implicit return. This is a feature of arrow function. You can read about it. You can do the following `person.child.map((child) => child.name)`